# Commit Not Found on Bitbucket on PreReceiveRepositoryHook

Tags: bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am trying to validate a file on PreReceiveRepositoryHook and been following examples from atlassion site(https://bitbucket.org/roadsidepicnic/atlassian-bitbucket-check-commits-hook)  and githup project (https://github.com/hmcmanus/yaml-validator-hook), neither one work because they can not find the commit just made. Anyone else facing same issue?

```
CommitRequest commitReq = new CommitRequest.Builder(repository, refChange.getToHash()).build();
Commit com1 = commitService.getCommit(commitReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian folks helped me solve the issue, here is the snippet, 
There are two remedies.  Choose one of:
1.)  Downgrade the version of git on your server to version 2.10.2 or older.
OR:
2.)  Update to Bitbucket Server 4.13.0 or newer. 
To do #2 in your first example you would adjust these values in that example's pom.xml.
From this:
4.3.2
4.3.2
To this:
4.13.0
4.13.0

more details @ https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/46816348/commit-not-found-on-pre-receive-hook